# Panel data Clustering

Tags: clustering

I have panel data of variable X consisting of 15 yrs-time points and 103 countries. I want to cluster countries in four group. Please suggest appropriate  method and software to run panel data clustering. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't necessarily need to take the time-component into account. Just treat your 103 countries as instances, where each instance is represented by a vector of length 15 (the yearly measurements of $X$ for this country) and run a simple $k$-means clustering with $k=4$.

You might want to check for different values of $k$, though, e.g. using the [elbow method](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/determining-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-3-must-know-methods/).

Comment: Thank you Edgar. So I should take one year data point for 103 countries and then run a simple k-mean clustering.